# How to make HTML combo box save values added by user in textbox?

Tags: html, html-select

I have made a combobox for a web page. It takes values from user into text box & adds those to list on double click in text box. I want to make user entered values permanently stored as option in list. How can I do it. One more question is how can I count the number of options in list so that I add an element next to that.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function AddListItem(form)
{

var TestVar = form.txtInput.value;
form.txtInput.value = "";
form.select.options[3]=new Option(TestVar, TestVar, true);

}
</script>
<head>

<body>
<form id='Form1'>
<input id='txtInput' type='text' maxlength = "5" size="5" ondblclick="AddListItem(this.form)"/>
<p>
<select id='select'>
<option>abc</option>
<option>cde</option>
<option>efg</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To permanently add you need a server-side script.

To temporarily add you can use javascript:

```
function addVal(newVal) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('select');
  var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");

  sel.addChildNode(opt);
  opt.innerHTML = newVal;
  opt.value = newVal; //(alternatively)
}
```

To count the number of options:

```
function countOpts() {
  var sel document.getElementById('select');
  return sel.options.length;
}
```

(only for conceptual use, not tested as functional)

Comment: I tried your code Steve it did not work,I adopted it to my form. Here is what I did,                                        " function AddListItem(form)
{
var TestVar = form.txtInput.value;
form.txtInput.value = "";

var sel = form.select;
//var count = sel.options.length;
var opt = form.createElement("OPTION");

sel.addChildNode(opt);
opt.innerHTML = TestVar;
opt.value = TestVar;
//form.select.options[count]=new Option(TestVar, TestVar, true);
}"                                                                   What I understood from ur code is it creates child nodes for one session

Comment: If I do it this way, it works but all newly added options are vanished when page is refreshed.                                   " function AddListItem(form)
{
var count = form.select.options.length;
var TestVar = form.txtInput.value;
form.txtInput.value = "";
form.select.options[count]=new Option(TestVar, TestVar, true);
} "

Comment: Comment 1 - not the session, just the current instance of the window. Comment 2 - Yep, that's the temporary thing working against you. See my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

You add an `<option>` dynamically like this:

```
function add(selectId, optText, optValue)
{
    var newOption = document.createElement("option") 
    newOption.text = optText;
    newOption.value = optValue;
    document.getElementById(selectId).options.add(newOption);
}
```

selectId is the id of `<select>`, `optText` is the text to be displayed in the dropdown and `optValue` is the value that will be sumbitted to the server.

For your code, call it as

```
<input id='txtInput' type='text' maxlength = "5" size="5" ondblclick="add('select', this.value, this.value)"/>
```

As you see, you don't really need to find the length of the options, but you *can* do it via `options.length`:

```
document.getElementById(selectId).options.length;
```

That said,

1. You might want to add this to the
   dropdown, as well as to pass to the
   server, to add to some table, for
   instance. You might have to do that
   call via AJAX, when you add it to
   the dropdown
2. Adding the new item
   on double click of the textbox is
   not very usable. On blur might be an
   option. Better is an 'Add' button after the
   textbox .

Comment: thanX a Lot Nivas:-) I did it this way before using ur code," function AddListItem(form)
{
var count = form.select.options.length;
var TestVar = form.txtInput.value;
form.txtInput.value = "";
form.select.options[count]=new Option(TestVar, TestVar, true);
}
"my code behaves like all newly added options are cleared on refresh. Then I check urs now & it also behaves same way.Bec u did it using 'createElement' so I was thinking urs options may stay at least for a session.I am trying to do it step by step. Now I need to get & render JSON data from php server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a server-side script then. When you submit the form, you can have a field that is 'remembering' all of the dropdown options:

The simplified HTML:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
  <input name='newDDoption' />
  <input type='hidden' name='ddStorage' value='<?PHP echo implode("|||",$ddOptions); ?>' />
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

The simplified PHP:

```
<?PHP
$ddOptions = explode("|||",$_POST['ddStorage']);
$ddOptions[] = $_POST['newDDoption'];

echo "<select>";
for($x=0;$x<count($ddOptions);$x++) {
  echo "<option>".$ddOptions[$x]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

To explain: PHP saves the ddOptions in the form -> User enters new option -> The form is submitted -> PHP finds the stored values -> PHP pushes on the new value -> PHP loops through and creates your permanent dropdown menu.